# Paypal PHP SDK payment status

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am using paypal php sdk. I have the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require __DIR__  . '/vendor/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';

$dev_ClientID = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$dev_ClientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
        new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
             $dev_ClientID     
            ,$dev_ClientSecret     
        )   
);

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal('1.00');
$amount->setCurrency('USD');
$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("https://www.somedomain.com/paypal_success.php")
    ->setCancelUrl("https://www.somedomain.com/paypal_cancel.php");

// Create the WebProfile
$presentation = new \PayPal\Api\Presentation();
$presentation->setLogoImage("http://www.yeowza.com/favico.ico")
    ->setBrandName("YeowZa! Paypal")
    ->setLocaleCode("US");

$inputfields = new \PayPal\Api\InputFields();
$inputfields ->getNoShipping(1);

$webProfile = new \PayPal\Api\WebProfile();
$webProfile
   ->setName('somename' . uniqid())
   ->setInputFields($inputfields)
   ->setTemporary(true);

$webProfileId = $webProfile->create($apiContext)->getId();

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setExperienceProfileId($webProfileId);

$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
    echo "\n\nRedirect user to approval_url: " . $payment->getApprovalLink() . "\n";
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    // This will print the detailed information on the exception.
    echo $ex->getData();
}
?>
```

I get the payment link but i still see the shipping info.

I have defined getNoShipping to true, maybe hooked web profile wrong. So thats one thing. The second thing I am not sure about is this.

I passed a payment and got redirected back to paypal_success.php with paymentId, token and  PayerID. How would I use these to receive info about the transaction. I wish to make sure it actually occured.

I tried the following:

```
$paymentId = $_GET["paymentId"];
$token = $_GET["token"];
$PayerID = $_GET["PayerID"];
echo "paymentId: " . $paymentId . "<br>";
echo "token: " .$token . "<br>";
echo "PayerID: " .$PayerID . "<br>";



$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/$paymentId");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$result = json_decode($response);


var_dump($result);
```

with the following result:

{ ["error"]=> string(13) "invalid_token" ["error_description"]=> string(35) "Token signature verification failed" }

Will appreciate any help rendered.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that would be tied to your experience profile ID that gets passed into the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the payment details using following call

```
$payment_details = PayPal\Api\Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
```

Here `$apiContext` is your api credentials that you have used to make transaction.

Also if you want to use curl then this following endpoint 
`$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/$paymentId");` is not correct to get payment details, rather you should use this endpoint `$curl = curl_init("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/$paymentId");`